# How do I print a string one word at a time in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, loops

I am trying to print a string one word per line using a loop. For example if the string is, 'I need practice', the string should print:
I'\n'
need'\n'
practice

My code so far looks like this:

```
phrase=input('enter a phrase: ')
  for char in phrase:
     print (char, end ='')
  if char == '':
    print('\n')
```

However, my output looks like this:

I need practice

Comment: `for word in phrase.split(' '): print(word)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function to split a string by spaces and that will give you back a list of words that you can then loop and print them out.

The function accepts a string that will be used as the delimiter (e.g ",") **if this argument is not specified or is None** it will run an algorithm that will consider a sequence of whitespaces as a single separator and hence, as a result, no matter how many spaces there are between the words you will get a list of words with no whitespaces at the start or the end of each substring.

```
phrase = input("Enter a phrase: ")
words = phrase.split()  # ['I', 'need', 'practice']
for word in words:
  print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `replace` the spaces with `\n` 's

> phrase=input('enter a phrase: ')
>
> words = phrase.replace(' ', '\n')

Note the space in the first argument of replace.